# Firebase SDK Not opening launcher activity when app is background

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using Firebase-SDK for sending push messages to my application.after processing two or three push notification events when I send third or fourth push to a device with the app in background mode, then on Tapping, notification it resumes that background activity instead of launching default launcher activity.is this bug in firebase-SDK. I am using firebase version 9.8.0.

**Steps to reproduce.**

kill the app and send push it is redirecting to desired activity after processing this push put app in background and send push. it will resume last activity with intent extras as null.

Comment: as a first step please update to the latest SDK version: 10.2.0

Comment: @DiegoGiorgini  ok then after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".activity"> 
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="extra" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

In Activity:

> getIntent().hasExtra("extra");

in payload:

> data.put("click_action",click_action);
>   data.put(click_action,argument);

your click_action should be the argument key.

Answer (score 1):

We can launch activity when app is not is memory or in background after receiving from FCM we have to send clickAction in data payload of notification and set action for a particular activity in manifest,
This will help you.

Comment: thanks for your response let me try it.because it is sometimes launching launcher activity without passing click_action in the payload.

Comment: i tried click_action attribute also but still after 3 or 4 times it is not working. i am using intent flags intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

Comment: @HardikMehta you have to manage notification when app is in background and when app is in foreground. For that you need send click_action in notification payload and in data payload also.

Comment: I also tried click_action but i m getting intent extras null can u please provide any small demo or other workaround.

Comment: @HardikMehta Have followed the steps.I hope your problem solved.

Comment: i launched that activity with Singleinstance mode and i am testing solution only problem is that although singleinstance activity is finished if i go to reecnt app screen from that that singleInstance activity get launched.

Comment: have u you faced such issue as mentioned in above comment?

Comment: @HardikMehta No, I have not faced this issue "singleinstance activity is finished if i go to reecnt app screen from that that singleInstance activity get launched".

Answer (score 1):

One workaround I've found is to use `android:launchMode="singleTask"` with launcher activity. Of course, singleTask might not be what you want, but in my case it works.